# How to add shortcuts of common email domains (gmail / yahoo / hotmail) to android tv keyboard?

Tags: android, email, keyboard, android-tv

I am trying to improve the user experience for users entering their email address in my app. Any idea how to add common email domains as keyboard shortcuts?

Please see the keyboard of other app that I have attached for reference. I am trying to find ways to populate my keyboard with gmail / yahoo / hotmail domains (just like in the image).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the [Creating an Input Method](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) docs as it talks about the  input method editor (IME) which is a user control that enables users to enter text.

> If you haven't worked with IMEs before, you should read the
>   introductory article Onscreen [Input Methods
>   first](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html).
>   Also, the [SoftKeyboard
>   sample](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/)
>   app included in the SDK contains sample code that you can modify to
>   start building your own IME.
>
> **Designing the Input Method UI**
>
> There are two main visual elements for an IME: the input view and the
>   candidates view. You only have to implement the elements that are
>   relevant to the input method you're designing.
>
> **Input view**
>
> The input view is the UI where the user inputs text in the form of
>   keyclicks, handwriting or gestures. When the IME is displayed for the
>   first time, the system calls the onCreateInputView() callback. In your
>   implementation of this method, you create the layout you want to
>   display in the IME window and return the layout to the system. This
>   snippet is an example of implementing the onCreateInputView() method:

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        MyKeyboardView inputView =
            (MyKeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.input, null);

        inputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
inputView.setKeyboard(mLatinKeyboard);

        return mInputView;
    }
```

> In this example, MyKeyboardView is an instance of a custom
>   implementation of KeyboardView that renders a Keyboard. If you’re
>   building a traditional QWERTY keyboard, see the KeyboardView class.

Comment: I was expecting some quick way to achieve this functionality but I guess, you need to create your own custom IME to get this feature. Thanks.